# " netsh wlan start hostednetwork " command not working no matter what I try

Tags: wifi

C:\Windows\system32>netsh wlan show drivers

Interface name: Wireless Network Connection

```
Driver                    : DW1501 Wireless-N WLAN Half-Mini Card
Vendor                    : Broadcom
Provider                  : Broadcom
Date                      : 21/01/2010
Version                   : 5.60.48.35
INF file                  : C:\Windows\INF\oem26.inf
Files                     : 5 total
                            C:\Windows\system32\DRIVERS\BCMWL6.SYS
                            C:\Windows\system32\bcmihvsrv.dll
                            C:\Windows\system32\bcmihvui.dll
                            C:\Windows\system32\drivers\vwifibus.sys
                            C:\Windows\system32\bcmwlcoi.dll
Type                      : Native Wi-Fi Driver
Radio types supported     : 802.11n 802.11g 802.11b
FIPS 140-2 mode supported : Yes
Hosted network supported  : Yes
Authentication and cipher supported in infrastructure mode:
                            Open            None
                            Open            WEP
                            Shared          None
                            Shared          WEP
                            WPA2-Enterprise TKIP
                            WPA2-Personal   TKIP
                            WPA2-Enterprise CCMP
                            WPA2-Personal   CCMP
                            WPA2-Enterprise Vendor defined
                            WPA2-Enterprise Vendor defined
                            Vendor defined  Vendor defined
                            Vendor defined  Vendor defined
                            Vendor defined  TKIP
                            Vendor defined  CCMP
                            WPA-Enterprise  TKIP
                            WPA-Personal    TKIP
                            WPA-Enterprise  CCMP
                            WPA-Personal    CCMP
Authentication and cipher supported in ad-hoc mode:
                            WPA2-Personal   CCMP
                            Open            None
                            Open            WEP
IHV service present       : Yes
IHV adapter OUI           : [00 10 18], type: [00]
IHV extensibility DLL path: C:\Windows\System32\bcmihvsrv.dll
IHV UI extensibility ClSID: {aaa6dee9-31b9-4f18-ab39-82ef9b06eb73}
IHV diagnostics CLSID     : {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}
```

I disabled and re-enabled it many times. Still no clue whats goin wrong I always get the error saying

"C:\Windows\system32>netsh wlan start hostednetwork
The hosted network couldn't be started.
A device attached to the system is not functioning."

The commands before that are running perfectly. The virtual adapter and everything is also enabled.

```
netsh wlan show hostednetwork
```

C:\Windows\system32> netsh wlan show hostednetwork

### Hosted network settings

```
Mode                   : Allowed
SSID name              : "Lathiyas"
Max number of clients  : 100
Authentication         : WPA2-Personal
Cipher                 : CCMP
```

### Hosted network status

```
Status                 : Not started
```

Then tried stopping the hostednetwork and tried again still the same error. I think there is some problem with the drivers. Dell N5010 Windows 7-32bit system. Please help.

Comment: Please ask questions like this on SuperUser. Stack Overflow is for programming questions.

Answer (score 14):

First of all go to the device manager now go to View>>select Show hidden devices....Then go to network adapters and find out Microsoft Hosted network Virual Adapter ....Press right click and enable the option....

Then go to command prompt with administrative privileges and enter the following commands:

```
netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow
netsh wlan start hostednetwork
```

Your Hostednetwork will work without any problems.

Comment: @kokbira Yeah, use Linux ;)

Answer (score 2):

At first simply uninstall wifi drivers and softwares
just keep wifi drivers
+
from device manager....network adapters...remove all virtual connections

then

Press the Windows + R key combination to bring up a run box, type ncpa.cpl and hit enter.

netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=”How-To Geek” key=”Pa$$w0rd”

netsh wlan start hostednetwork

netsh wlan show hostednetwork

its working for me and on others PC.

Answer (score 2):

Same issue.

I solved the problem first activating (right click mouse and select activate) from control panel (network connections) and later changing to set mode to allow (by netsh command), to finally starting the hostednetwork with other netsh command, that is:

1.- Activate (Network Connections) by right click

2.- netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow

3.- netsh wlan start hosted network

Good luck mate !!!

Answer (score 1):

If none of the above solution worked for you, locate the Wifi adapter from "Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network Connections", right click on it, and select "Diagnose", then follow the given instructions on the screen. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=dhiraj key=7870049877
```

Comment: This is a perfectly good line. And if it doesn't give any errors, you can run with it.

Comment: Not true, @NickySmits, I have exactly this problem. This line runs perfect, but the "start" line doesn't. (Yes, wifi enabled).

Answer (score 0):

If you have a wifi button or switch on your laptop make sure it is turned on!  Then use the netsh commands that other people have stated

Answer (score 0):

This was a real issue for me, and quite a sneaky problem to try and remedy...

The problem I had was that a module that was installed on my WiFi adapter was conflicting with the Microsoft Virtual Adapter (or whatever it's actually called).

To fix it:

1. Hold the Windows Key + Push `R`
2. Type: `ncpa.cpl` in to the box, and hit `OK`.
3. Identify the network adapter you want to use for the hostednetwork, right-click it, and select `Properties`.
4. You'll see a big box in the middle of the properties window, under the heading `The connection uses the following items:`. Look down the list for anything that seems out of the ordinary, and uncheck it. Hit `OK`.
5. Try running the `netsh wlan start hostednetwork` command again.
6. Repeat steps 4 and 5 as necessary.

In my case my adapter was running a module called `SoftEther Lightweight Network Protocol`, which I believe is used to help connect to *VPN Gate* VPN servers via the SoftEther software.

If literally nothing else works, then I'd suspect something similar to the problem I encountered, namely that a module on your network adapter is interfering with the hostednetwork aspect of your driver.

Comment: in my case i found a `Microsoft Virtual adapter` was interfering with the hostednetwork i tried to disable it but it runed it self again, then i disabed it quick and runned the command it started the hosted network normally